# is it bidah (innovation) to say Quran "Sharif"?

Tags: quran, practical-islam, bidah

is it bidah (innovation) to say Quran "Sharif"?

Some people say that, It is bidah (innovation) to say Quran Sharif instead of Quran majeed. Because in quran, Quran is not called as Quran Sharif. So is it bidah to say Quran Sharif? And what "Sharif" means?

Comment: The term bid'ah is related to worship. Do you worship the qur'an? You may use any appropriate term or attribute.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I understand but what does mean "Sharif"?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not Bid'ah... It is a description that carries a praise, which does not diminish the status of the Quran.

And Bid'ah cannot be loosely used everywhere like that. The classical scholars have [defined Bid'ah](https://www.islamiqate.com/3637/how-do-the-classical-scholars-define-bidah) to have two meanings: something that did not exist or was not done during the era of the Prophet (saw) endorsed by scholars like Shafi'i, Ibn Hazm, Nawawi, Qurafi and al-Izz al-Din ibn Abd al-Salam et al or something that opposes or clashes with the Qur'an or Sunnah stated by scholars like Shatibi, ibn Rajab al-Hanbali, Mullah Ali al-Qari al-Hanafi et al. In essence both are saying the same thing - anything not rooted in revelation is unacceptable.

Allah knows best